# How would I use datename in a case statement in SQL

Tags: sql, database

How do I use a case statement to determine whether the current date is a saturday, sunday or a weekday?  I have tried the following so any pointers on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE day = (SELECT CASE aday
                                        WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Saturday' THEN 'Sat'
                                        WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' The 'Sun'
                                        ELSE 'Weekday');
```

Comment: what are your table field definitions for `day` and `aday` ?

Comment: `case aday` should just be `case`. And you are missing the `end`. Also no reason to write this as a subquery though that is valid.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE day =  CASE 
                                        WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Saturday' THEN 'Sat'
                                        WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' Then 'Sun'
                                        ELSE 'Weekday' end;`

Comment: Thanks Martin, thought that had sorted it but I'm in Oracle not SQL SERVER and no joy, have put it up again as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE day = (
    SELECT CASE DAYNAME(aday)
        WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 'Sat'
        WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 'Sun'
        ELSE 'Weekday' END
)
;
```